# AJAX and JQuery parseerror

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jsp

I'm trying to show an error div in a form and hide it when I make a key in the text field. The problem is given when I import the Jquery library in the **JSP** and in the **JS** I declare the Jquery function. I do not run the submit form and in the Chrome console, Firefox, IE shows me a **parseerror** error. In the comes to enter the **AJAX** call (I added a console.log ()). I tried to comment the dataType line and even change the type of json to text in the **AJAX** call and it still gives me a **parseerror**. If I do not comment the **dataType** line does not enter the **AJAX** call. It stays in the **$.ajax**

**This image is the console output of the code I left here.**

**[image: JS]** 
**JSP code:**

```
spring:url value="/resources/js/jquery-3.4.1.js" var="jqueryJs" />
            <script src="${jqueryJs}"></script>
        <%-- <script type="text/javascript" src="/openiam-ui-static/js/common/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>--%>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/openiam-ui-static/js/common/openiam.common.js"></script>
        <%--<script type="text/javascript" src="/openiam-ui-static/moment/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>--%>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/openiam-ui-static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/openiam-ui-static/bootstrap/js/bootbox.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/openiam-ui-static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-notify.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/openiam-ui-static/bootstrap-ui/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
```

JS code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $("#error").hide();
    $("#otp-form").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        sendOTP();
    });

//  $("#smsCode").on("input",function(){
//        if($("#smsCode").val().length < 1){
//          $("#error").hide();
//        }else{
//          $("#error").show();
//        }
//    });
});


function sendOTP() {
    $("#error").empty().hide();

    var otpToken = {};  
    otpToken["smsCode"] = $("#smsCode").val();
    otpToken["authToken"] = $("#authToken").val();
    otpToken["postbackURL"] = $("#postbackURL").val();

    $.ajax({
        url : "otpToken",
        type : "POST",
        //dataType : "json",
        data : JSON.stringify(otpToken),        
        success : function(data) {                  
            console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
            if(data.code == 200) {
                var redirectURL = data.redirectURL;
                if(redirectURL != null && redirectURL != undefined && redirectURL.length > 0) {
                    window.location.href = redirectURL;
                } 
                console.log(data);
            } else if(data.code == 103) { 
                //Account Locked
            } else {
                $("#error").empty().hide();
                $("#error").show();
                $("#error").append("<a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>×</a>");
                $.each(data.errorList, function(idx, val) {
                    $("#error").append($(document.createElement("div")).text(val.message));
                });
            }
        },
        error : function(e) {
            console.log("ERROR: ", e);
        },
        done : function(e) {
            console.log("DONE");
            disableButtons(false);
        }
    });
}
```

**This image is the console output of the code with decomposed dataType.**

[image]

Comment: Why do you return HTML? Your code is expecting JSON - `otpToken` should return `{ "redirectUrl":"https://...." }` but why use Ajax at all when you redirect??? Just submit the form and redirect in the JSP

Comment: @mplungjan I am correcting an error that I do not develop but another person. I think the AJAX call makes it for the error and check the status of the network (404,200 ..)

Comment: Anyway the issue is that you are not getting JSON back

Comment: @mplungjan im gonna try with this. Thank you.As soon as I have it, I tell him the solution